# Unittest framework in Databricks

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, pytest, databricks

```py
import unittest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, when



# Create the DataFrame
spark_df = spark.sql('select * from dna_scr_l3.vw_dna_cdm_md_bom')

class MdbomTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_blank_spaces_count(self):
        # Apply the blank spaces count operation and retrieve the result
        blank_spaces_count_df = spark_df.select([
            count(when((col(c).substr(1, 1) == ' ') & (col(c).substr(-1, 1) == ' '), c)).alias(c)
            for c in spark_df.columns
        ])
        
        # Perform assertions
        for column in blank_spaces_count_df.columns:
            self.assertEqual(blank_spaces_count_df.collect()[0][column], 0)

    def test_null_persentage_in_col(self):
        col_null_cnt_df = spark_df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in spark_df.columns])
        
        # Perform assertions
        for column in col_null_cnt_df.columns:
            self.assertEqual(col_null_cnt_df.collect()[0][column], 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Want run unittest but getting error

> ### ERROR: /databricks/kernel-connections/76ddb9359db2cb425c430527d257d2fe22bc38113daa396b5589d6712ace288c (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
>
> AttributeError: 'DummyMod' object has no attribute '/databricks/kernel-connections/76ddb9359db2cb425c430527d257d2fe22bc38113daa396b5589d6712ace288c'
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.005s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3386: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
> warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
> SystemExit: True
> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit: True

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that to use `unittest.main` function with Databricks you need to set `exit = False` in the list of arguments otherwise it will be terminate the current Python shell. It also makes sense to explicitly pass `argv` as single-element list, to avoid use of `sys.argv` that on Databricks contains parameters that were used to start Python subprocess. (see [documentation on unittest.main](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)):

```py
test_runner = unittest.main(argv=[''], exit=False)
test_runner.result.printErrors()

if not test_runner.result.wasSuccessful():
  raise Exception(
    f"{len(test_runner.result.failures)} of {test_runner.result.testsRun} tests failed.")
```

Also, in the notebook the `__name__` is always set to `__main__`.

But take into account that by default, the `unittest` autodiscovery may not work so you may either explicitly register classes/test cases, or write some code for auto-discovery of the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
unittest.main()
```

use this:

```
unittest.main(argv=[''], exit=False)
```