# Unit Test in Databricks Notebook

Tags: function, unit-testing, pyspark, databricks

So I was trying to unit test a function in the databricks.
And I got this error.

> ### ================================================
> ERROR: /databricks/kernel-connections/7caabde12c8241952a4700622d9d3579894bc9517d9c63854a34e2f63c5a298c (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
>
> AttributeError: 'DummyMod' object has no attribute '/databricks/kernel-connections/7caabde12c8241952a4700622d9d3579894bc9517d9c63854a34e2f63c5a298c'
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.002s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3386: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
> warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
> SystemExit: True
> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit: True

---

I have created a simple function:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def process_data(data):
    """
    This function processes the input DataFrame and returns a new DataFrame.
    """
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    
    # Perform some data processing
    processed_data = data.select("id", "name").filter(data["age"] > 18)
    
    return processed_data
```

And I have created this unit test:

```
import unittest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class TestExampleFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
    
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.spark.stop()
    
    def test_process_data(self):
        # Define input data
        input_data = [(1, "Alice", 25), (2, "Bob", 17), (3, "Charlie", 30)]
        columns = ["id", "name", "age"]
        
        # Create input DataFrame
        input_df = self.spark.createDataFrame(input_data, columns)
        
        # Call the function to process the data
        processed_df = process_data(input_df)
        
        # Define expected output data
        expected_data = [(1, "Alice"), (3, "Charlie")]
        expected_columns = ["id", "name"]
        
        # Create expected output DataFrame
        expected_df = self.spark.createDataFrame(expected_data, expected_columns)
        
        # Compare the processed DataFrame with the expected DataFrame
        self.assertEqual(processed_df.collect(), expected_df.collect())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76849493/unittest-framework-in-databricks/76850075#76850075

Comment: running "unittest.main(argv=[''], exit=False)" helped